# How can we port an ASP Project in ASP.Net Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I am trying to improve the features of website that is already done with Classic ASP.

I am willing to work on other modules with ASP.Net
Can I port it to an ASP.Net project .
What's easier to port a Classical ASP project to ASP.Net or ASP.net MVC?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it.

Really it depends on what you want to do here. Do you want to add a new stand alone feature? That's sort of easy, just put the new app in a virtual directory. Do you want to share authentication? That's way more complicated. Do you want to share session? Forget it, it's not worth the pain.

Porting = rewrite. Pretty much a complete rewrite, unless your ASP site has some COM components you wrote which you could repurpose and call from .NET. As it's a rewrite there's no easiest for this, whatever you find easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to migrate `Classic ASP` web applications to `ASP.NET` sites at the early age of ASP.NET. What it got produced is just another `ASP` site running on `.NET Framework` sandbox and it turned out to be a garbage sooner or later.

ASP.NET is completely a different paradigm than ASP, although the name stayed same. ASP is completely depends upon inline codes where you make all your business logic in your ASP files (more or less). ASP.NET has its own level of execution at a different level of its total life cycle. Even though ASP.NET MVC has no similarity with ASP.NET Webforms.

My suggestion would be to rewrite your application for better maintainability and manageability. You may consider ASP.NET MVC on your design phase for better concern of separation.